# How to stop using cache manifest on a live site

Tags: html, caching, html5-appcache, cache-manifest

I changed my cache.manifest file to the following:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
NETWORK:
*
CACHE:
FALLBACK:
```

This triggered an update to my site. 
I tried adding a "#" to the manifest file and then removed the `manifest="cache.manifest"`from my page.

This triggered the cache to be updated again, even though the reference to the manifest was gone. The console indicated it was still being loaded from cache.

I even tried renaming my cache.manifest file and it still was being loaded from cache.

How in the world can I safely stop using cache manifest? I have a completely new version of my site I want to roll out, but if cache manifest is still trying to cache the new site, that will be a disaster for all my visitors who do not know they need to clear their browser cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the trick.
It seems I need to keep the old cache.manifest but change (not remove) the reference to a non-existent manifest file.

Presumably, I'll need to keep the broken reference there for several years in case I have visitors who only visit periodically.